# jquery autocomplete with categories clickable links is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I implemented autosearch module for my website,its working fine.
Now problem is,when user type it start suggesting results,now i want to make these results clickable.
My code is

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" style="font-size:20px;padding-left:5px" name="query" id="search" required />
```

Jquery

```
  $( function() {
   $.widget("custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
   _renderMenu: function(ul, items) {
    var that = this, 
    currentCategory = "";
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
    if (item.category != currentCategory) {
     ul.append("<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>");
     currentCategory = item.category;
       }
     that._renderItemData(ul, item);
     });
     }
    });
   $( "#search" ).catcomplete({
   source : function(request,response){
    var term = $("#search").val();
    $.ajax({
      type : "GET",
      url : "ajax/auto_search.php",
      dataType : "json",
      data : {term : term},
      success : function(data)
      {
        console.log(data);
        response($.map(data.list, function(item) {

                return {
                    value: item.content_title,
                    label: item.content_title,
                    category: item.category_name
                };  
            }));
            }
           });
          }

         });
        });
```

**NOTE:** When user hover on suggested results it throws this in console jqueryui.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined